# Set variable type to number but still get a NaN in output

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having an issue with a Nan error in my typescript. I have set a variable type to number and loop throuh an element where I get all the different balance amounts. They come in the form of "$..." like $10.00 and $20.00, so I do a replace and then finally include each balance amount into the total sum balance variable.

However, in my console log it outputs:

```
Expected: NaN
Actual: 20.00
```

I am not sure why that is. Why does it think it's not a number and how can this be rectified (should show 20.00)

```
balance: Selector;

 this.balance = Selector('.balance');
 this.balanceTotal = Selector('.balance-total ');

  async validateTotalBalance() {

    let sumBalanceTotal: number = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < (await this.balance.count); i++) {
      let amount = await this.balance.nth(i).textContent;
      amount.replace('$', '');
      let convertedAmount = Number(amount);
      convertedAmount.toFixed(2);
      sumBalanceTotal += convertedAmount;
    }

    console.log('Expected: ' + sumBalanceTotal);
    console.log(
      'Actual: ' + (await this.balanceTotal.textContent).replace('$', '')
    );
}
```

Comment: `NaN` is of type `number`, paradoxically.

Comment: The key thing to do is to look at what the actual content of `amount` is. Apparently, it has characters in it that mean `Number(value)` returns `NaN`. For example, `Number("5,300")` results in `NaN`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh ok, I was hoping `Number(amount`) would convert it from string to number but I am guessing it doesn't convert it

Comment: @BruceyBandit It tries to, but it can only parse numbers that look like JS literals, failing by returning `NaN` instead. Also, `convertedAmount.toFixed(2)` does nothing here (it doesn't alter the number and returns a string representation of it)

Comment: Got it working now thanks to multiple comments and answers. Thank you everyone. I will upvote one answer and mark the other one as best answer as both answers helped. I'll one up the comments as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
amount.replace('$', '');
```

This line is not storing the result of the `replace` so amount still has `$` in it after, which could be why the value is `NaN`

Comment: Oh ok, what is the best way to remove this as I don't see a remove option?

Comment: `amount = amount.replace('$',  '');`

Comment: Oh of course - dumb me

Answer (score 1):

This is because `toFixed()` returns a string. Use `toFixed()` until calculations are done or only before you need to present the data.

Comment: That's right, but not the cause of the problems here. It returns a string, which the OP doesn't store anywhere.